# How to load all images when controller did load in tableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
kategoriManager.fetch(){kategoriItem, error in
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               // Update UI
               self.parentCategoryTableView.reloadData()
           }
       }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       if (tableView == categoryDetailTableView) {
           let kategoriDetailItem = selectedKategori[indexPath.row]
           let kategoriDetailCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
               withIdentifier:"categoryDetailCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryDetailCell
           kategoriDetailCell.categoryDetailLabel.text = kategoriDetailItem.name
           return kategoriDetailCell
       }
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
           withIdentifier:"parentCategoryCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell
       let kategoriItem = kategoriManager.kategoriItem(at: indexPath.row)
           cell.parentCategoryLabel.text = kategoriItem.name
           cell.parentCategoryImageView.load(urlString: (base_img + kategoriItem.image!))
       return cell
   }
```

I have a table view like above, but when the controller is load the table view. Only **cell.parentCategoryLabel.text** is shown. The image is not loaded until I scroll the table view.

```
class CustomImageView: UIImageView {
    
    var imageURLString : String?
    
    func load(urlString : String){
        
        imageURLString = urlString
        
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        
        image = nil
        
        //imageCache exist,and use it directly
        if let imageFromCache = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString) {
            self.image = imageFromCache
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url! as URL) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data)
                        if self?.imageURLString == urlString {
                            self?.image = imageToCache
                        }
                        imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: urlString as NSString)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That is my load image function, can I load all image in tableView without scrolling it? And can I do it without any library like sdWebImage or kingFisher. I preferred native solution cause I don't want to make the app slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this following answer from other question, that already solve my question

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73840635/18088674

So after read that answer, I define width and height before image load, or maybe you can add default image before load from url image has been loaded